# Opencv svm trainAuto error: bad argument (while cross-validation one or more of the classes have been fell out of the sample)

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to cross validate my training data with the function trainAuto and i get the error::: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (While cross-validation one or more of the classes have been fell out of the sample. Try to reduce ) in do_train.

When i change trainAuto function to just train it works, but i need trainauto. I need to validate every data point i have, which are 70 points. What i am trying to do is to cross validate every point in my trainingData array. All my data points and labels are stored in my labels[70] and trainingData[70][2744] array. When trying to cross validate my training data i copy every row in my trainingData[70][2744] except the one that should be tested on, that one is copied to the testData array. This should be done 70 times, so 70 tests. Here is my code and any help would be appreciated.

```
//my labels and points are stored here
int labels[70] = {};
float trainingData[70][2744] = {};

//this is where the copy of my test, labels and training data should end up for the cross validation
int labelstrain[69] = {};
float trainingDatatrain[69][2744] = {};
float testData[2744] = {};

//looping through everything and extracting test point, labels for the points and training data
for(int o = 0; o < 70; ++o){
     memcpy(testData, trainingData[o], sizeof(testData)); 

    for(int p = 0; p < 70; p++){

        if(o != p){
            labelstrain[p] = labels[p];
            copy(trainingData[p], trainingData[p] + 2744, trainingDatatrain[p]);
        }
        else{
            cout << "label that was left out: " <<labels[p]<< endl; 
        }

}

    //creating matrix of my labels, test point and training data
    Mat labelsMat(69, 1, CV_32SC1, labelstrain);
    Mat trainingDataMat(69, 2744, CV_32FC1, trainingDatatrain);
    Mat testDataMat(1, 2744, CV_32FC1, testData);

    //here is my problem where i get a error. Only train here works fine
    svmLin->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));
    svmPoly->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));
    svmRbf->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));
    svmSig->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));
    svmChi2->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));
    svmInter->trainAuto(ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat));

    //predicting on my point that is not in my trainingdata
    float predictLin = svmLin->predict(testDataMat);
    float predictPoly = svmPoly->predict(testDataMat);
    float predictRbf = svmRbf->predict(testDataMat);
    float predictSig = svmSig->predict(testDataMat);
    float predictChi2 = svmChi2->predict(testDataMat);
    float predictInter = svmInter->predict(testDataMat);
}
```

Comment: Update: noticed that my loops and how i put in my rows to the array i wanted to train and test on was wrong. That was the problem :).